# Populating Textboxes from combobox is showing column names

Tags: vb.net, combobox

I am trying to populate text boxes from a combo box but can only populate them with the column names from my database as shown below.

[example of error]:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/b7rHh.jpg

Here is my code.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'DB PATH
    dbSource = "Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=C:\USERS\MICHAEL\DOCUMENTS\GODFREYHOLMES\GHAPP2018\GHAPP2018\BIN\DEBUG\GH2018.MDF;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=True;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False"

    'Customer ComboBox
    Try
        sql = "SELECT FirstName,LastName FROM Customer"
        cmd.CommandText = sql
        cmd.Connection = con
        con.ConnectionString = dbSource
        con.Open()
        rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader

        While rdr.Read()
            ComboCustomer.Items.Add(rdr(name:="FirstName").ToString)

        End While

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("error...", "Read Error Recovery", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)


    Finally
        con.Close()
    End Try

End Sub

Private Sub ComboCustomer_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboCustomer.SelectedIndexChanged

    If ComboCustomer.SelectedIndex <> -1 Then

        'Populate Customer Panel textboxes
        Try
            sql = "SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE FirstName = FirstName"

            'Run time parameters to avoid SQL injections

            cmd.Parameters.Add("FirstName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ComboCustomer.SelectedItem.ToString
            cmd.CommandText = sql
            cmd.Connection = con
            con.ConnectionString = dbSource
            con.Open()
            rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader

            While rdr.Read

                TxtboxCustomerID.Text = ("CustomerID").ToString
                TxtBoxFirstName.Text = ("FirstName").ToString
                TxtBoxLastName.Text = ("LastName").ToString
                TxtBoxAddress.Text = ("Address").ToString
                TxtBoxZip.Text = ("Zip").ToString
                TxtBoxTele.Text = ("Telephone").ToString
                TxtBoxAccType.Text = ("AccType").ToString


            End While

        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("error...", "Read Error Recovery", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)

        Finally
            cmd.Parameters.Clear()
            con.Close()

        End Try

    End If
```

Comment: Anyway, please read [Ask] and take the [Tour].  You could get rid of most of that code if you fill a DataTable and use DataBinding.

Comment: Thank you for your reply

Comment: What do you think the result of `("CustomerID").ToString` is?  Please read [ask] and take the [tour] to get the most out from SO (we will know when you actually do it)

Comment: i didn't have the reader before ("CustomerID").String.